# Allow only the login and password reset page for guest on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using the following solution in my functions.php file to force visitors that aren't logged in to do so:

```
// force visitors to log in to see the page
function admin_redirect() {
if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
   wp_redirect( home_url('wp-admin') );
   exit;
}
}
add_action('get_header', 'admin_redirect');
```

But now I'm facing the problem that no-one can reset their password, because they are redirected to /wp-admin/.

How can I exclude the URL /my-account/lost-password/ ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

replace pageid with page id or slug of forget password page

```
if ( (!is_user_logged_in()) && (!is_page(pageid))) {
   wp_redirect( home_url('wp-admin') );
   exit;
}
}
add_action('get_header', 'admin_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

My final solution:

```
function admin_redirect() {
if ( (!is_user_logged_in()) && (!is_page("my-account"))) {
   wp_redirect( home_url('wp-admin') );
   exit;
}
}
add_action('get_header', 'admin_redirect');
```